# Shell scripting and -e parameter

Tags: shell

I'm writing a shell script that create a database and store values into keys in a database.file.

I got a test that catched my attention and i'm wondering why this is happening.

```
./shellscript put key -e
```

The expected behavior would create a file:

```
key <-> -e
```

For some reason my shell script can't even catch the "-e" and even when printing $1, passing -e as first parameter.

Comment: Are you on Linux?  Does the parameter show up if you set environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT to 1?  If so, there's an explanation...

Comment: Hi, yes i'm on linux  and i tested with POSIXLY_CORRECT set to 1 but nothing have changed.

Comment: `key <-> -e` is the contents of the file, right? The way your question is phrased, it looks like it's the name of the file, which would be legal but very odd.

Comment: Have you tried `echo "$@"` or similar inside the script — maybe to a log file?  If so, is the `-e` option in there?

Comment: turn on shell debug/trace facility with `set -vx`, then you can see what values your script is processing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. Do you use "echo" in your shell script to print command line arguments? If yes: Replace every

```
echo foobar
```

by

```
printf '%s\n' foobar
```

Does the problem disappear now? (Depending on your "echo" version, it interprets
`-e` and/or `-n` as options, rather than as arguments.)